# the application may be doing too much work on its main thread message

Tags: android, android-fragments

Am developing an android app where am using multiple fragments in its UI for different purposes

like, I have 4 fragments below which gets executed onCreate()

```
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager on = getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction on = on.beginTransaction();
onTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_on, new On());
onTransaction.commit();

android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager tw = getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction twTransaction = tw.beginTransaction();
twTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_tw, new TW());
twTransaction.commit();

android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager th = getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction thTransaction = th.beginTransaction();
thTransaction.replace(R.id.th, new TH());
th.commit();

android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fo = getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction foTransaction = gfo.beginTransaction();
foTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_fo, new Fo());
foTransaction.commit();
```

but, am getting these messages in logcat

```
I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 30 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 22.032MB for 348072-byte allocation
```

though these doesn't have any effect on the performance of the app but i fear these might lead to force closing of the app in low end devices. (As per my tests app becomes bit slow in low end devices, which is not a good sign)

Is there any better way to populate multiple fragments? if so , please guide me how to do this

Comment: May be you should check your 4 fragment's initial codes (include onAttach(), onCreate(), onCreateView() etc.) to see whether they have do two much during initialization.

Answer (score -1):

Add **android:largeHeap="true"** this manifest and Go for **async task**. Don't Go for main thread.

Comment: still am getting the same message